# read file with r+ in node js

Tags: node.js, fs

Is it possible to use r+ options with readfile in node.js file system library? If so, how do you accomplish that? I have been scratching my head on how to do it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: -1 from me, have you read the Node.JS documentation? http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

Answer (score 2):

You can change the flag in the options object.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/path/to/file', {flag: 'r+'}, function(error, data) {

});
```

[Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback)

Comment: I should have phrased it better. I found that one, but inside the callback of readfile, how do you write the file at the same position you just read from? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You could use a mixture of `fs.open`, `fs.read` and `fs.write` and then use the offset/length/position to write back into the file.